# Finding newline in Notepad++ since merger of \r and \n

Tags: notepad++, newline

Since a (somewhat) recent update to **Notepad++**, `\r` no longer exists, and `\n` does what `\r` and `\n` used to do together. This is annoying, since I can no longer to `\n` to simply search a file and look at things at the beginning of a line, because `\n` is always at the end of a line now, so I see the previous lines only. Is there a setting or `add-on` that I can use to add `\r` back in?

Comment: I figured it out a while ago, and I thought I'd share, in case someone comes across this: Just use the ^ symbol, it matches the start of the line, and $ matches the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Select this menu item

edit --> EOL Conversion --> Windows Format

Comment: \n is still at the end of the line when I do that, though. I want \r at the end, and \n at the beginning.

Comment: /n is a meta character, it stands for line feed, has ascii value 0x0A.  It indicates the end of the line, so software draws it there, when it draws it all.   When the data is stored in a file there are no line breaks so  \n continuous with the charactors on the next line.

Comment: I understand that, but the problem is that Notepad++ shows only the first line from the set of characters that a search matches in the search window, so if I'm trying to quickly look around a document for a bunch of identical sets of characters at the beginning of lines, the search window only shows the lines before what I'm actually searching for, because \n is at the end of those prior lines.